# Count PHP Function is not Adding Values

Tags: php, database, list, joomla, count

I have a simple PHP script which loads a list of items from a Joomla database table.

`$result = $db->loadObjectList();`

After this, I am trying to count the total number of items in this list:

```
foreach($result as $key=>$value){
$items = $value->item;
$count = count($items);
echo $count;
}
```

The for each loop is outputting `111` rather than adding those values and providing the total of `3`.  I know this must be a simple fix with the way I am pulling the value in a loop, but I cannot seem to make the connection.  Any ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: So show where your code is actually doing anything that could be considered adding! Perhaps you meant to put `$count += count($items);`

Comment: it's $items[] = $value->item; not $items = $value->item;

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? What is $value->item?

Comment: I can't see any sum in your code. You may want to create a variable beofre the loop, then incrementing in the loop, and display at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$count = 0;
foreach($result as $key=>$value){
    $items = $value->item;
    $count += count($items);
}
echo $count;
```

Comment: awesome!  thanks for the quick answer.  you got to it so fast that I have to wait 8 minutes to award...

Comment: Ahah you're welcome ;) Also, If you need more explanation around your mistake, feel free to ask !

Answer (score 0):

I think $items is meant to be an array. If I am right, you may do smt. like the following:

```
$result = $db->loadObjectList();
$items = array();

foreach($result as $key=>$value){
    $items[] = $value->item;
    $count = count($items);
    echo $count; //why echo here and why not outside the loop?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count the total number of items with help of following line:

```
$result = $db->loadObjectList(); //your existing code line
echo count($result); //which gives you the total numbers
```